# How to pretty print a GumTreeDiff ITree?

Tags: java, parsing, open-source, abstract-syntax-tree, pretty-print

I am using [GumTree](https://github.com/GumTreeDiff/gumtree) to parse a Java file into an ITree, which is GumTree's data structure that represents an AST. I then modify the ITree by performing Actions on it, which are GumTree's representation of Inserts, Updates (renames, etc.), Deletes, and Moves. I would like to then unparse the resulting modified ITree. In other words, I am trying to pretty print the AST.

I have looked in the ITree methods (core/src/gumtreediff/tree) and tried toPrettyString, but that just returned the string "15" which is the [type](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/ASTNode.java.html) of the top AST node of the tree (a compilation unit).

The GumTree wiki on GitHub has no mention of unparsing or pretty printing. A Google search doesn't help because I think GumTree is too obscure.

Wondering if I should "just" write my own unparser.

I am using release 2.0.0 of GumTree.

Comment: Currently implementing an unparser. I hope to add this functionality to GumTree soon.

Comment: Were you ever able to get this working? Does GumTree now support unparsing, or is there some alternative concrete syntax tree that preserves source code formatting?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but there is a built-in method

```
toTreeString()
```

which will return a multi-level indented version of the tree.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm looking for. I've looked through all of the provided API and what I want doesn't exist. I have been in contact with the main Gumtree developer, and I'm working on implementing the unparser functionality that I need.

Comment: Oh I see. You're trying to turn an ITree back into something that looks like human-readable code. Can you not accomplish this with a simple post-order traversal? I guess it's not quite that simple. Well, good luck!

Comment: Thanks; I am doing a traversal but yeah it's not that simple. I have to add all the terminal characters back in and I found a parse ambiguity. But so far my solution works for many cases.